# how to disable CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM through make menuconfig or make nconfig

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I need to disable a `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` option in my Linux kernel and recompile it. Why? I was told to do so. I know I can disable it by simply commenting it out in the `.config` file, but I need to see how it is done through `make menuconfig` or `make nconfig`. Why? This is for a demo and I need to be able to show it. Does anyone know how to do it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you look under "Kernel Hacking"?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I did. This was exactly my thought at first. I've tried several options but none of them seem to change the value of `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM`.

Comment: 1) make menuconfig 2) hit "/" 3) type "devmem" 4) ??? 5) Profit!

Comment: @Notlikethat It worked. Post this as an answer and I will mark it as an accepted one.

Comment: (Example use case: «NOTE: if running flashrom -p internal for software based flashing, and you get an error related to /dev/mem access, you should reboot with iomem=relaxed kernel parameter before running flashrom, or use a kernel that has CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM not enabled.» https://libreboot.org/docs/install/index.html )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't know your way around menuconfig, hit <kbd>/</kbd> to search (à la vim and friends), and type in enough of the config option to narrow it down, e.g. "strict_devmem" or just "devmem". You can then hit one of the numbers in parentheses to jump straight to the relevant menu. It's an absolute lifesaver when you need to check on a whole bunch of random options (e.g. making whatever development defconfig you've got play nicely with a systemd filesystem).

In this specific case, it should be available under "kernel hacking" as "filter access to /dev/mem".